# Prolog open source community, code repository, blogs, forums

Tags: artificial-intelligence, prolog

I find useful

1. groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.prolog/topics
2. cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/areas/
3. google.com/Top/Computers/Programming/Languages/Prolog/Implementations/
4. allisons.org/ll/Logic/Prolog/Examples/
5. prolog.info/

Maybe there are else useful links? Please share it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mailinglist full of smart people: http://www.swi-prolog.org/Mailinglist.html

Comment: I want to see a study comparing the IQ of participants of the Prolog mailinglist to the IQ of the participants of the Haskell mailinglist!

Answer (score 2):

Also useful is the Prolog tag on StackOverflow and the Prolog forum on Reddit

**LINKS**
[Reddit Prolog](http://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/)
[Prolog questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog)